# BGE Chaging the position of a vertex in real time

Tags: game-engine, vertex-groups, soft-body

I'm using the BGE and I need to change the position of a group of vertex of a soft-body while the game is running. I've tried with the code below but I don't see any change. If I print the new position of the vertex I can see in console that the value change but in the soft-body I don't see anything different. I've tried using obj.reinstancePhysicsMesh(obj,mesh) at the end of the code but that change the position of the entire mesh. How could I do?

```
import bge
import bpy
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController( ) 
own = cont.owner
scn = bge.logic.getCurrentScene( )
obj = scn.objects["object1"]
mesh = obj.meshes[0]
for v in range(0,1000):
    vert = mesh.getVertex(0, v)
    vert.XYZ = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: I think it is not possible with a soft body, because Blender calculates every Frame a new position for every vertice with the position of the vert in the frame before. So Blender dont expect a position changement while running, Blender is using the mesh of the frame bevore. (Its just a guess, I'm not shure.)(It works fine with other Physics types)

Comment: Thank you. I see, if I change the object to rigid body it works.

Comment: Note that the loop should look like: `for v in range(0,mesh.getVertexArrayLength(0)):` otherwise an exception occurs.

Comment: Yes, look at the code used in this video, the waves are by changing mesh vertices in real time PREVIEW
1:56
blender game engine :waves
YouTube · vicent adnawm
Jan 29, 2016